# Comparar 2 arrays y devolver array de lo que se repite JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for

*Que estoy haciendo mal?*
*Podrían explicarme?*
*No quiero usar foreach, filter o includes, lo quiero hacer con ciclos anidados*.

**El 18 rindo algo parecido, ayuda por favor!**

```
    function actividadesEnComun(persona1, persona2) {      
    // La funcion llamada 'actividadesEnComun' recibe como argumento dos arrays de actividades (strings) llamados 'persona1' y 'persona2'
      // y debe devolver un array de strings con las actividades en comun ( aquellas que se repiten ) entre cada array.
      // ej: persona1 = ['leer', 'comer', 'pasear', 'dormir', 'jugar']
      //     persona2 = ['comer', 'dormir', 'futbol']
      // actividadesEnComun(persona1, persona2) => ['comer', 'dormir']
      // Tip: podes usar ciclos for anidados.
      // Tu código aca: 
     
            persona1 = ['Parkour', 'Gimnasia', 'Natacion'];
            persona2 = ['Parkour', 'Paracaidas', 'Remo'];
    
            let coincidencias = [];
    
            for(i=0; i < persona1.length; i++){
            for(j=0; j < persona2.length; j++){
            if (persona2[j] === persona1[i]){
          coincidencias.push(persona2[j]);
        }
      }
    }
          return console.log(coincidencias);
    }
```

Comment: `console.log()` es para mostrar valores en la consola, no para devolverlos. ¿Intentaste dejar solo `return coincidencias;`?

Comment: Tienes razón también tu, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabo de copiar y pegar tu código y funciona tal cual quieres. Devuelve por consola el array con las coincidencias entre `persona1` y `persona2`.

Lo único que faltaría sería invocar la función para que se ejecute.

Comment: Amigo, estás en lo cierto, no invoqué la función, perdón, soy nuevo y voy de apoco, gracias!